# issue with node -> websocket: error 426 Upgrade Required

Tags: node.js, websocket

i have one issue with node module - websocket, yesterday all worked good, but today, after i run node, i see just one message in browser "Upgrade Required".
this my code:

```
// first file ws.js:
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 9000 });
wss.on("connection", function(ws){
    ws.send("Welcome to cyber chat");
});


// seccond file ws-client.js
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");
ws.onopen = () => {
    setTitle("Connected to Cyber Chat");
};

ws.onclose = () => {
    setTitle("DISCONNECTED");
};

ws.onmessage = payload => {
    printMessage(payload.data);
};

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('message');
    input.value = '';
};

function setTitle(title) {
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = title;
}

function printMessage(message) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = message;
    document.querySelector('div.messages').appendChild(p);
}
```

i have seen so much same problems, and not just here, on this site, but not find normally short and correct answer, or just long answer, but step by step.